# source ~/.bashrc returns command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate

This command longer works.

```
andy@7 ~> source ~/.bashrc
END: command not found
```

What is wrong?

This is my prompt.

```
  andy@7 ~>


# for examples
# DO NOT FORGET TO DO THIS AFTER EDITING THIS FILE.

# source ~/.bashrc


# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
# This shows directories and files in different colors
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
# Sets my prompt for Every mate terminal session
export PS1='\u@\h \w> '

# To use, countdown Number of seconds
# countdown 300 for 5 mins and countdown 7200 for 2 hours
# countdown 180 for 2 mins
countdown() {
    start="$(( $(date '+%s') + $1))"

while
    time=$(( $start - $(date +%s) ))
    [ $time -ge 0 ]

do
        printf '%s\r' "$(date -u -d "@$time" +%H:%M:%S)"
        sleep 0.1
    done
        {
    for ((volume = 35; volume <= 45; volume += 2)); do
        amixer -D pulse sset Master ${volume}% > /dev/null
        sleep .5
    done
    
} &

cvlc --play-and-exit "/usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Alarm-sound-buzzer.mp3" > /dev/null 2>&1
#set back to original volume
amixer -D pulse sset Master %65
printf  "Tea is ready.\n"
}
#
```

Comment: Can you include your .bashrc file here?

Comment: @cocomac I added .bashrc to my post.

Comment: @Terrance This is my prompt. andy@7 ~>

Comment: @Terrance andy@7 ~/bin> echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: Ah, I see you're running MATE terminal.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Try setting debug before sourcing ,bashrc ,,, `set +x`  ,,, to see what comman are executed.

Comment: The `END: command not found` error may be coming from one of the files that is sourced by the ~/.bashrc file, rather than from the file itself - check your `~/.bash_aliases` file for example

Comment: @steeldriver I will check out my aliases.

Comment: What are the consequences if I can not get this fixed? :-)

Comment: @soren-a As was suggested, try to debug the problem, but the command would be  set -vx to have v=echo input line and x to output the line as executed, after substitutions, etc. Note the -x sets and +x removes these options

Answer (score 0):

Search through all your hidden files in your home folder looking for the `END` command sitting by itself without a comment `#` in front of it.  Remove it from the file or comment it out with a `#` in front of it.

```
grep END ~/.* 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: @ Terrance I replaced  .bashrc with a virgin copy. No change?

Comment: @fixit7 Where did you get the "virgin" copy from?  I know that there is one located in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` that is a default that goes into all new accounts that get created.  I guess it is entirely possible that another file like `.profile` might have the issue.  Have you tried running `grep END ~/.* 2>/dev/null` to see if `END` might be on a line by itself where it is not following a `#`?

Comment: I got it from my 22.04 installation. There are no instances of END.

Comment: Thanks Terrance. I found an END on a line by itself in .bash_aliases. Problem solved. :-)